# opendatabase in SQLCipher taking time Android:

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I am using SQLCipher it is working fine. I have one performance issue with this `openDatabase` method. My code is

```
SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath,
                databasePassword, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

This also working fine. But my problem is it takes 3 to 4 seconds time (I found time lagging in Logcat). Because of this the activity show slow response.

**Note:**
I am calling this code from `onCreate` method after set `setContentView(R.layout._list);`

Am i doing right? Is there any other way to open database.

Is it right to call openDatabase from `onCreate`?

Comment: You should always be doing disk I/O on a background thread. Beyond that, use Traceview to determine precisely where your time is being spent.

Comment: I add log before SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath,
                databasePassword, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); and after this. Exactly here it takes 3 seconds time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem. Once my application is open i've open my database and save that (`static` method) open it from all the `activities`. I am not sure which is the right way or not. But it solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The performance issue you are seeing is most likely due to SQLCipher key derivation. SQLCipher's performance for opening a database is deliberately slow, using PBKDF2 to perform key derivation (i.e. thousands of SHA1 operations) to defend against brute force and dictionary attacks (you can read more about this at http://sqlcipher.net/design). This activity is deferred until the first use of the database.

Comment: So. How to improve the performance when opening the database?

Comment: The best option is to cache the database connection so that it can be used multiple times without having to open and key the database repeatedly. Treat the database as a singleton; open it only once at startup, so subsequent access will not trigger key derivation.

If that won't work, you could weaken key derivation. SQLCipher can use fewer rounds of PBKDF2 when deriving the key to make the database open faster. However, it is much weaker from a security perspective and not recommended. With that caveat, this is how to reduce KDF iterations:

http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#kdf_iter